# Does the extension of an element of $W^k$ by $0$ still lie in $W^k$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and $Z$ a closed subset of $U$ . We denote by $W^{k}(U)$ the Sobolev space of functions whose derivatives (in the sense of distribution theory) up to order $k$ are in $L^{2}$. Assume that  $f\in W^{k}(U\setminus Z)$, then **can we imply that the extension $\tilde{f}$ of $f$ by $0$ is still in $W^{k}(U)$ ? Why?**  (This may be a stupid question )

Comment: If you want to use the Sobolev extension theorem you must assume some regularity on the boundary of $U\setminus Z$ for instance smooth or cone condition.

Comment: @Iwassuspendedfortalking, Thank you. However $Z$ is a  measure zero set. Can we obtain some information just from the definition of distributions?

Comment: The function should be $0$ on the border if $k>n/2$, if not it will automatically be discontinuous when you take the extension, and so not in $W^k$.

Comment: And yes, you need some assumptions about the border of the set, I do not see why distributions would prevent you to do that. This is not about the value of the function on the border but about the value of the function near the border.

Comment: @LL3.14 .Thank you. you are right. .However, the set of measure zero does not affect the integral value while the weak derivative is defined by integral. So it seems to be true that $\tilde{f}\in W^{k}(U)$. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that if you have two parts of your domain really close but separated, and you are really big on one side and really small on the other side, and both parts will "see" each other when you extend your function.

Comment: To expound on what LL 3.14 says, you want derivatives to be preserved close to the boundary from both sides of the domain. If the boundary is irregular this is close to impossible without additional assumptions on $f$. Try even for a straight boundary to see why this is difficult (but doable). In fact the (standard?) proof of the Sobolev extension is to straighten out the boundary and reflect the derivatives about the boundary, to ensure that the derivative is well-defined.